# add conditional formatting to a macro for a row if a cell in that row is less than a certain value

Tags: excel, vba

[image]

I'm struggling to find the right way to do this in a Macro. I know I can do conditional formatting but I'm trying to save a bit of time and have a macro that does most of the work and all I'll have to do is put in the remarks. I've read a couple other threads but couldn't find what works for me and I'm not really good at understand Macros and just started messing with them. I also tried recording the process as a macro but that did not work.

What I want to happen starting with N2;

If a Cell in column N is less than 3 highlight the whole row Green

If a Cell in column N is 4 or 5 highlight the whole row Yellow

If a cell in column N is greater than 5 highlight the whole row Red

Comment: As a short answer: `For Each x In ActiveSheet.Range("N2" ,ActiveSheet.Cells(ActiveSheet.Rows.Count, 14).End(xlUp)).Cells: x.EntireRow.Interior.Color = 0 - (x.Value >= 4) * 255 - (x.Value <= 5) * 65280: Next` :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
Sub Demo()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim lastRow As Long
    Dim cel As Range

    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2")  'change Sheet2 to your data sheet
    With ws
        lastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "N").End(xlUp).Row  'last row in Column N
        For Each cel In .Range("N2:N" & lastRow)    'loop through all values in Column N
            If cel.Value <= 3 Then                  'if cell value is less than or equal to 3
                cel.EntireRow.Interior.Color = vbGreen  'color entire row with green color
            ElseIf cel.Value = 4 Or cel.Value = 5 Then  'if cell value is equal to 4 or 5
                cel.EntireRow.Interior.Color = vbYellow 'color entire row with green yellow
            Else                                        'any othe cell value i.e. cell value greater then 5
                cel.EntireRow.Interior.Color = vbRed    'color entire row with green red
            End If
        Next cel
    End With
End Sub
```

See image for reference.

[image]

Comment: @SlyWolf - If you want to color only the `Column L` (as per the image in question) then change`cel.EntireRow.Interior.Color` to `.Range("L" & cel.Row).Interior.Color`.

Comment: what you gave me is exactly what I'm trying to do the black out has email information I don't want getting out but I am running into a problem

 Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("-")

this keeps highlighting in yellow if I remember correctly it's because it doesn't recognize the sheet name yet that is the sheet name. am I doing something wrong?

Comment: @SlyWolf - I didn't get what you are saying. Is there a problem with `Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("-")` or coloring yellow?

Comment: @Mrig- After I run the macro I receive a "Run time error '9': Subscript out of range". When I hit debug to see what the problem is, "Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("-")"  is highlighted in yellow

Comment: @ Mrig -  Yes that is correct. Could that be the problem?

Comment: @SlyWolf - That's not an issue. Make sure you copy the code in the module under the workbook with worksheet `-`. Probably more than one workbook is open.

Comment: Figured it out. I was trying to do it in Module 1 under personal instead of under Shee1(-) I really appreciate your help!